# TFS Alerts on Iteration ID Change Not Firing

Tags: tfs

I have setup an alert on our TFS server attached to the Work Item Changed event using Alerts Explorer.  The only clause I have in the alert has a field of Iteration ID and an operator of Changes.  My filter expression is :

"ChangedFields/IntegerFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.IterationId']/OldValue" <> "ChangedFields/IntegerFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.IterationId']/NewValue"

However, when I change the Iteration of a work item I never receive an email.  Other alerts based on the Work Item Changed event on the same server are coming through with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'm not sure what "Iteration ID" stands for, but when you change the "Iteration" in your work item, then "Iteration Path" gets surely changed.

So reform your clause for "Iteration Path" instead:

```
"CoreFields/StringFields/Field[ReferenceName='System.IterationPath']/NewValue" under '\'
```

This corresponds to a configuration like this:

[image]